# mostrar datos de un select en un input

Tags: php, html, jquery

Tengo 3 combos dependientes que funcionan perfectamente bien. Pero el ultimo de ellos, debe mostrar el dato seleccionado en un input.
Al seleccionar del primer combo, activa el segundo, de este se hace la seleccion y carga los datos en el tercer combo.
El problema es que cuando lo hace no se ve en las opciones de este select, pero el dato, y su valor estan alli.
les muestro el código y la secuencia de imagenes:

```
<!-- ========== COBERTURA ========== -->
                        <div class="titulo-form"><h5>Cobertura</h5></div>
                        <div id="cobertura" class=" col-md-12">
                            <select name="selectDepartamento2" id="departamento" onchange="cambia2()" class="form-control" required>
                                <option value="">Seleccione</option>
                                <option value="Amazonas">Amazonas</option>
                                <option value="Ancash">Ancash</option>
                                <option value="Apurímac">Apurímac</option>
                                <option value="Arequipa">Arequipa</option>
                                <option value="Ayacucho">Ayacucho</option>
                                <option value="Cajamarca">Cajamarca</option>
                                <option value="Callao">Callao</option>
                                <option value="Cuzco">Cuzco </option>
                                <option value="Huancavelica">Huancavelica</option>
                                <option value="Huánuco">Huánuco</option>
                                <option value="Ica">Ica</option>
                                <option value="Junín">Junín</option>
                                <option value="La_Libertad">La Libertad</option>
                                <option value="Lambayeque">Lambayeque</option>
                                <option value="Lima">Lima</option>
                                <option value="Loreto">Loreto</option>
                                <option value="Madre_de_Dios">Madre de Dios</option>
                                <option value="Moquegua">Moquegua</option>
                                <option value="Pasco">Pasco</option>
                                <option value="Piura">Piura</option>
                                <option value="Puno">Puno</option>
                                <option value="San_Martín">San Martín</option>
                                <option value="Tacna">Tacna</option>
                                <option value="Tumbes">Tumbes</option>
                                <option value="Ucayali">Ucayali</option>
                            </select> 
                            <select class="form-control" id="provincias" name="selectProvincia2" onchange="cambiaDistrito2()" required>
                                <option>Seleccione la Provincia</option>
                            </select>
                            <select class="form-control" id="distritos2" name="selectDistrito2" required><option>Seleccione el Distrito</option>
                            </select>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cobertura1" name="cobertura1" placeholder="Ingrese la cobertura separada por comas. Ej; Lima,San Miguel,Cercado">
                            <script>

                                $(document).ready(function () {
                                    $("#distritos2").change(function () {
                                        var value = $(this).val();
                                        //alert(value);
                                        $("#cobertura1").val(value);
                                    });
                                });
                                
                            </script>
                        </div>
```

[image: combo 1]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que tiene que ver esto con php???

Answer (score 0):

Lo más razonable seria que revisara el CSS que tiene el elemento  asociado o los elementos hijos , que tipo de CSS tiene porque la causa de que no se vean podría ser que el 'color' no está definido o toma el mismo valor que su 'background'

```
.class_select_distrito option
{
 color: #fff;
 background: #333; 
}
```